# How can a QToolBar know where it is?

Tags: c++, qt, toolbar

In Qt, when moving a QToolBar, one can use the QToolBar::topLevelChanged(bool) signal to know if the the QToolBar is floating or docked.

When the QToolBar is docked, how can one **get the Qt::ToolBarArea** (LeftToolBarArea, RightToolBarArea, TopToolBarArea, BottomToolBarArea) **where the QTookBar is docked**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try this :

```
Qt::ToolBarArea QMainWindow::toolBarArea ( QToolBar * toolbar ) const;
```

Hope this helps !